# Finding how many different letters there are in a string in Python

Tags: python, string, pangram

I'm very new to Python 3 and programming for that matter. I trying to find an algorithm to find out when a sentence is a pangram. I've solved that side of the bargain thanks to a function with the aid of the string module, but I also need to find out how many different letters there are in non-pangrams (switched them to lowercase already).

Any help would be very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Try looking at the length of the set of letters:

```
len(set(yourstring))


In [8]: set('lowercase')
Out[8]: set(['a', 'c', 'e', 'l', 'o', 's', 'r', 'w'])

In [9]: len(set('lowercase'))
Out[9]: 8
```

Don't forget to remove spaces.

```
In [10]: len(set('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'.lower().replace(' ', '')))
Out[10]: 26
```

Comment: How is punctuation handled?

Comment: @KyleStrand You could check with `isalpha`

Comment: I used string.punctuation.
for c in string.punctuation:
...  line = line.replace(c, "")

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to count punctuation, try this:

```
s = "It's the economy, stupid!"
t = set(c.lower() for c in s if c.isalnum())
len(t) #returns 13
```

Or, if you only want letters:

```
s = "It's the economy, stupid!!!11!!"
t = set(c.lower() for c in s if c.isalpha())
len(t) #returns 13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
s = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
count = len(set(c.lower() for c in s if c != ' '))
```

Here, count will be 26.